# Java Return Button Pressed

Tags: java, game-development

I am creating a Game in Java and I have a main menu with buttons on it, I need someway to return the button that was pressed so that I can use it in a different class.  I do not know how to do this.  Does anyone have any idea?

I get the button with e.getSource() in the actionPerformed method.
I tried returning the button, but that did not work.

Thank you very much.

Here is some code:

Menu Class

```
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
    Object button = e.getSource();
    return button
}
```

Other Class

```
public static void createGameScreen() {
    if(Menu.button == Menu.button1) {
         // do something here
    }
}
```

Comment: Where's the code? Another idea would be to use some kind of eventbus.

Comment: Passing the entire button object is frankly, wasteful. Wouldn't it be much be much better to just pass an integer that represents the button?

Answer (score 1):

You wouldn't so much return which button was pushed but rather assign code to that action (or at least that is how I'm interpreting your question). For that button assign a listener like this. This is how I prefer to do it. There may be a better way.

```
button.addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener() {
    public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent e) {
        buttonBoardActionPerformed(e);
    }
});
```

```
public void buttonActionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
    // Do some stuff
}
```

Basically you're linking the button directly to the action rather than assigning one individual listener for the whole thing. Easier to debug *IMO*. Read up on [THIS TUTORIAL](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/events/intro.html), also.

Answer (score 0):

For what you type, I think you wrote something like:

```
buttonProcess = new JButton("Process");
buttonProcess.set//bounds,actionlistener,etc.
if (e.getSource().equals(buttonProcess)){
 //do some stuff
 return buttonProcess;
}
```

You can try using a static variable defined in an Auxiliary classor in the class of your UI.

e.g:

```
public class AuxClass{
 public static Object PROCESS_BUTTON; //YOu can replace Object by Component or JButton
}

//then in your first UI code
 if (e.getSource().equals(buttonProcess)){
     AuxClass.PROCESS_BUTTON = buttonProcess;
    }

//then in your other UI:
if (AuxClass.PROCESS_BUTTON !null && AuxClass.PROCESS_BUTTON instanceof JButton){
 //Do what you want here
}
```

Comment: yes it does not matter, since your variable is static and public there's no problem, it can be used no matter what package are you in.